# How to use junit configuration parameters in an ant script

Tags: junit, ant

I have multiple projects and I am currently trying to set some configuration parameters for junit in ant. However I have trouble doing so.
Is there a way to set junit configuration parameters in ant? For example I try to set junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true but I am not sure which tag to use.

```
<project>

<property name="output.dir" value="${basedir}/build"/>
<property name="src.test.dir" value="${basedir}/src/test"/>
<property name="build.classes.dir" value="${output.dir}/classes"/>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${output.dir}"/>
</target>

<path id="junit.platform.libs.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/lib/junit-platform/"/>
</path>

<path id="junit.engine.jupiter.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/lib/jupiter/"/>
</path>

<target name="compile-test" depends="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.test.dir}"
       destdir="${build.classes.dir}">
       <!-- our tests only need JUnit Jupiter engine
       libraries in our compile classpath for the tests -->
       <classpath refid="junit.engine.jupiter.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="test" depends="compile-test">
    <junitlauncher>
        <!-- include the JUnit platform related libraries
        required to run the tests -->
        <classpath refid="junit.platform.libs.classpath"/>

        <!-- include the JUnit Jupiter engine libraries -->
        <classpath refid="junit.engine.jupiter.classpath"/>

        <classpath>
            <!-- the test classes themselves -->
            <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
        <testclasses outputdir="${output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
            <listener type="legacy-brief" sendSysOut="true"/>
            <listener type="legacy-xml" sendSysErr="true" sendSysOut="true"/>

        </testclasses>
    </junitlauncher>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long long time, but pretty sure you don't do this in ant. Put
`junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true` in `src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties` and commit it.